# What does 「１歳遅らせる」 mean?

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage

Context:

> ５月の素案で示した「**７０代での発症を１０年間で１歳遅らせる**」という初めての数値目標は参考値に格下げし、患者の精神的負担にならないよう配慮した。

Source: https://www.sankei.com/life/news/190618/lif1906180018-n1.html

I understand the sentence in bold as,

Delay the outbreak of illness in 70 year olds, in 10 years, by one year (?)

Am I understanding this correctly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

70代で is "in their seventies" and it modifies 発症. 10年間で refers to the period of this plan/project. 1歳 refers to how much the onset is expected to be delayed.

> ７０代での発症を１０年間で１歳遅らせる
>   In the next 10 years, (we will) delay the onset (of dementia) of people in their seventies by one year

Comment: Why is the 歳 counter used here instead of 年間？

Comment: 1年 is usually not wrong, but 1歳 only refers to the difference in age (e.g., 彼は私より3歳若い), so it makes the sentence easier to understand. Roughly speaking, they are trying to increase the average age of the onset of dementia by one year.